# How to analyse signal where one sample (timestamp) captures multiple data points

Tags: fft, autocorrelation, pulse

I have a process that captures interactions between a source and a sink.  Unfortunately, the timestamp on the sample is one day.  This means that regardless of the number of interactions (flows of varying volumes) on a given day, they all have the same timestamp.

Practically this means my signal consists of daily samples where the number of interactions on a given day is anywhere between 1 and +1000.

I would like to be able to analyse the data to get the following:

- what days are similar and if repeated, how often?
- what interactions are similar and if repeated, how often?

I have tried autocorrelation and FFT but to do that I was just using the number of interactions per day and padded out the data so that it was continuous over an entire year i.e. included days where there were no flows/data captured.  However, that approach doesn't capture any information about the interactions themselves.

I have thought of treating each day as a pulse train by ordering the interactions each day by amplitude but I don't know what I would use as a sample rate ... or even if that approach makes sense.

Is there a good way to approach this or a name for this situation that I can start researching?

Comment: we'd need to know more both about the observed phenomenon (for example, what's its bandwidth, or how fast can it change/can you bound its derivative?) and about the observation process (anything that describes the sample instant distribution would help, probably really *anything*).

Comment: This looks to me more like a statistics problem. I don't think classical signal processing is going to help much here. I would probably start by creating histograms for each type of interaction. Something like "Interaction A" occured 0 times on 37 days, 1-10 times on 64 days..." and so on. And a histogram for overall number of interactions likewise. You can also do it the other way around. Then take a sharp look at the data and decide how to go on.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm trying to understand the phenomenon based on the data I have.  The flows are just units but could be dollars, gallons, light flashes, etc.  But the data comes bundled by day of occurrence.

Comment: @Max I will add an example.  I have done something similar but used a scatterplot of #interactions vs day.

Comment: @Max the boundary between statistics and signal processing are basically non-existent. Look for example at compressive sensing!

Comment: @MikeB2019x without any information about what you observe, we can't help you. You *will* have to tell us your prior knowledge about this. It **cannot** be any of these things – it's exactly one thing, and what it is contains information that might help us solve your question. Without additional information, we simply can't help you, as your problem remains unsolvable. So, tell us what it **actually** is that you're measuring.

Comment: @Max by rhe way, your histogram method is a good idea! Your sharp look is probably meant to reveal *autocorrelation properties* of the stochastic process; these are exactly what is captured by questions like "what's the signal bandwidth". So, without noticing, you're doing classical signal processing! We're really asking for the same thing: For Mike to describe the stochastic process in probabilistic terms. Any info helps, I'd say, because as it's written now, we simply cannot infer anything about anything.

Comment: You are right of course. It's just that I usually tackle every problem  in with SP in mind, while this particular problem provoked images of Excel Sheets. 

Comment: The more you go into the signal-analytic side of signal processing, the more you'll feel that understanding, estimating and dealing with the statistics of a signal is a fundamental concept in signal processing :) If something feels like you should be doing a histogram in Excel, maybe you should ask yourself "What numerical result do I get from that, with which formula could I describe that outside of Excel, and how would I then use the result to process my signal?" and then you're really doing processing of noisy/stochastic signals :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have to disagree with your p.o.v. about having to know what I'm actually measuring.  The challenge is to capture the patterns in the measurements.  _Then_ I can try and understand why that behaviour is so given the source.  To do otherwise is to prejudice my analysis of the signal ... a lesson I learned a long time ago in gas turbine fault prevention; look at what the data is telling you, not at what you think you should see.

Comment: @MikeB2019x heh, I don't really think we're in contradiction here: If you're doing some analysis without realizing *why* you're doing that, you're not any less biased – you're just less aware of it. Your fault prevention example still goes back to *what* you actually looked at when considering the data: That decision alone already "contains" an inherent model of what a turbine is, and how I can observe it.